# How to make Accordion open one at a time in Elementor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, elementor

I have made my own accordion in elementor using CSS and Javascript. If works fine, except for one problem: they stay open when  other tabs are opened. How should I modify the code, so that the other tabs collapse when one tab is opened.

Here is the CSS code.

```
    body:not(.elementor-editor-active) .toggle-content{
        display: none;
    }
    
    .toggle-trigger {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .arrow i{
        transition-duration: 0.5s;
    }
    
    .tab_active .arrow i{
        transition-property: transform;
        -ms-transform:rotate(45deg) !important; /* IE 9*/
        transform: rotate(45deg) !important;
        transition-duration: 0.5s;
    }
```

And here is the JavaScript.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        jQuery(".toggle-trigger").on("click", function(){
            let $this = $(this);
            
            if($this.hasClass('tab_active')){
                
                $this.removeClass('tab_active');
                $this.next(".toggle-content").slideUp(200);
                
            } else {
                
                $this.toggleClass('tab_active');
                $this.next(".toggle-content").slideDown(200)
                
            }
        })
    });
```

The class .toggle-trigger is applied to the inner-section which is to be used a the title-tab and .toggle-content is applied to the inner-section which slides down on click.
The class .arrow is for the icon to change its orientation on click.

Also, when the accordion is opened, the position of the tab moves a bit up and the content slides down, how  should I change it so that the position of the tab is fixed and only the content slides down?

I have tried using addClass instead of toggle class and removing the tab-active class using jQuery('.toggle-trigger).removeClass('tab-active') but it didn't work. Also, according to suggestions to this question on StackOverflow I also tried to remove class from other tabs using not($this). I am new to JavaScript and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 jQuery(".toggle-trigger").on("click", function(){
     let $this = $(this);

     const $currentActive = jQuery(".toggle-trigger.tab_active");

     $currentActive.next(".toggle-content").slideUp(200);
     $currentActive.removeClass('tab_active');
        
     $this.addClass('tab_active');
     $this.next(".toggle-content").slideDown(200)
});
```

You need to clear the active first, then add active class on the current tab.

Comment: I tried this, and unfortunately, using this code the content doesn't slide down on click.

Comment: Can you send the HTML code?

Comment: I'm using elementor to build the site, so I don't know how to exactly send you the html code for this portion. It would be great if you could guide me. Or else I will just send you the code for a new page which only has these elements

Comment: Is your site online? If so you can send me link and I will check it there.

Comment: I have identified the html code though, Let me know if this is useful:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/10bvhUQZkTEA33EIjp6Etgy2XzdfNdkKw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The site is not online unfortunately.

Comment: I updated the code.. Please check now. I tested this locally and it is working

Comment: Works Like A Charm! thanks, I too tried to edit the Syntax for the original code you posted, as it looked like it should work. However, I couldn't identify it, Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Great. I had an extra closing parentheses. I just noticed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try closing all open tabs before opening the selected tab

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    jQuery(".toggle-trigger").on("click", function(){
        let $this = $(this);

        // close all open tabs except clicked
        $(".toggle-trigger").not($this).removeClass('tab_active');
        $(".toggle-content").not($this.next(".toggle-content")).slideUp(200);

        // toggle clicked tab
        if($this.hasClass('tab_active')){
            $this.removeClass('tab_active');
            $this.next(".toggle-content").slideUp(200);
        } else {
            $this.addClass('tab_active');
            $this.next(".toggle-content").slideDown(200);
        }
    });
});
```

> Also, when the accordion is opened, the position of the tab moves a
> bit up and the content slides down, how should I change it so that the
> position of the tab is fixed and only the content slides down?

You could try adding a CSS `position: relative` to the parent element of the tab. This will fix the position of the tab relative to its parent while the content slides down below it

```
.parent element {
   position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, This also works well! I tried closing all open tabs but I was not using the correct syntax.